# Two possible questions arising when figuring out prepositional object vs. adverbial complement in question method

Tags: grammar-identification

> Goethe, den man bei Bezugnahme auf seine Werke häufig nur mit dem Familiennamen bezeichnet, war nicht nur ein hoch talentierter Schriftsteller und Theaterautor, sondern war unter seinen Zeitgenossen auch als Jurist Politiker und Naturwissenschaftler mit einer hervorragenden Beobachtungsgabe bekannt.

In the above, I want to figure out if "mit dem Familiennamen" is an object or adverbial. Following the scheme [in this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50787/51342), I create two questions:

1. Wie bezeichnet man Goethe?
2. Womit bezeichnet man Goethe?

Now, I have trouble identifying which is the correct question to use to figure out the object class of the above. How do I discern which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's a prepositional object. The relevant verb phrase is *jemanden  mit etwas(Dat) bezeichnen*. This is in general the case when *mit* tells an ingredient.

- Sie hat die Suppe mit Liebe gekocht.

The adverbial *mit jemandem* on the other hand tells who accompanies something.

- Sie hat mit ihrem Bruder Schach gespielt.

With some verbs there's however a grey area that you can tell from word order:

- Er hat mit der Familie seinen Geburtstag gefeiert.

That's an adverbial *mit der Familie*, and the verb phrase is *etwas feiern*. You can tell that because there's the noun accusative object directly in front of the verb block at the end.

- Er hat seinen Geburtstag mit der Familie gefeiert.

That on the other hand is a prepositional object *mit der Familie*, and the verb phrase is *etwas mit jemandem feiern*. There's only prepositional objects and directional adverbials between the noun accusative object and the verb block at the end.

The grey area is that the family accompanies the party, but it's also an ingredient to it. This is a family party. Not just some party the family by chance met at.